# Javascript: Find out which element was clicked without attaching any eventlistener to it?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am confused on finding an approach to resolve this issue. Consider below html

```
<body>
  <div id="parent" onclick="myFunc">
     <div id="child-a"></div>
     <div id="child-b"></div>
     <div id="child-c"></div>
     <div id="child-d"></div>
     <div id="child-e"></div>  
  </div>
</body>
```

Event listener is attached to the parent element. If a user clicks on lets say 'child-c', is there any way to find out using "myFunc" that which div was clicked? In this case 'child-c'. Any possible solution using pure JS or jQuery?

Let me know if more explanation is required. Thank you for helping.

-Nishant

Answer (score 10):

Yes, use [`target`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/event.target):

```
function(e){
    // e.target is the clicked div
}
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/Paulpro/AfA4t/

Comment: Thanks, works great. I dn't have reputation to 'up' ur answer. :(

Answer (score 4):

```
$("#parent").click(function(e){
   console.log(e.target);
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/4bC6K/

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can check the event's `target` property which will indicate the element that was clicked. You can read more about event properties [here](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_properties.html).