# How can I find which element was clicked

Tags: jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Javascript: Find out which element was clicked without attaching any eventlistener to it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7130232/javascript-find-out-which-element-was-clicked-without-attaching-any-eventlisten)

If I have the following html, is it possible to tell which element the user clicked on using JQuery?

```
    <div id="left">
      <div id="item1">1</div>
      <div id="item2">2</div>
    </div>
```

---

```
  $('#left').click(function(){

  });
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Paulpro/AfA4t/ from http://stackoverflow.com/a/7130259/1273830

Answer (score 4, accepted):

do you mean:

```
$('#left').click(function(evt){
    console.log( $(evt.target).attr("id") ); //shows either item1 or item 2
});
```

Demo: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arfCV/)

Comment: @AspiringAqib It covers exactly the same as this answer, maybe a little less. I'm not upvoting duplicate answers.

Comment: Yes, this is it, thank you. Where can I learn more about JQuery? I really need to learn this. I've been to the JQ site several times and don't understand it. What I need are the basics. Can you recommend something to me, please?

Comment: @user1709311 http://api.jQuery.com and http://docs.jquery.com/How_jQuery_Works

Comment: @user1709311 you can find lots of tutorials form jQuery on the net, such as:: http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials , http://jqfundamentals.com/ .. there are lot more, hope you will find the links useful..

Comment: w3schools.com and go to jquery!

Comment: hey man i do not copied your answer! i done it in javascript way and you in pure jquery way!

Comment: Thanks guys! I've bookmarked all of them and will be dedicating some of my day to learning more about this.

Comment: @AspiringAqib I never said anything about copying, and yours is no less jQuery than this one.

Comment: @user1709311 don't use w3schools. It's widely inaccurate at places. See http://w3fools.com/

Comment: for me if you really want to learn JQuery and how its working , you must read HeadFirst JQuery

Comment: Thanks Jan. I'll take your advice on w3schools. I've found inaccuracies with back end code there too.

Answer (score 3):

Try using $(this) to know which element is clicked

```
$('#left div').click(function(e){
 alert($(this).attr("id"));
  });
```

Comment: What if you want `#left` clickable as well?

Comment: Thank you KJA. All of these answers work. :)

Comment: Jan, I only want what's inside of the #left element, not the #left element itself.

Comment: @user1709311 if this answer works for you then you should use it instead of the other one.

Comment: Jan, does this one only select what's IN the #left element? If so, then this is the one I need.

Answer (score 2):

```
  $('#left div').click(function(e){
  var s = e.target.id;
  alert(s);
  });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/CyV3j/

Answer (score 1):

I am not a copier! lets get in pure js way!

```
document.getElementById('left').onclick = function(e) {
    var s = e.target.id;
    alert(s);
}
```

​​​​​​​​​​

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/CyV3j/1/